# how to crop a image circle in iphone sdk

Tags: uiimageview, uibutton, uipickerview, crop

I'm trying to create an image for a custom style UIButton using an image from the camera roll on iPhone. The button has a circular background and effectively appears as a circle. Now I need an image to go in the middle of the button that also appears round.

anyone can help me please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You must have set the corner radius of the button's layer to make it circular.
But you cant do same with an image accurately.

You need to set the image property of the UIButton for the states you want.
But more importantly make sure the image is also round.

Images cannot be round , but If you use a PNG, it supports transparency so have an image with corners transparent such that image looks circular.

```
btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[circularBtn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```